# Flutter appbundle/apk build failed! (Android Studio)

Tags: android, flutter

Unable to build the release bundle, tried upgrading packages, upgrading flutter, flutter clean, nothing worked.

```
Initializing gradle...                                              2.0s
Resolving dependencies...                                           7.9s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                                                                        
Note: E:\Softwares\64bit\androidDevelopmentKit\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.0+7\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseadmob\AdRequestBuilderFactory.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: E:\Softwares\64bit\androidDevelopmentKit\flutter\.pub- 
cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-3.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionHandlerPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: E:\Softwares\64bit\androidDevelopmentKit\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.2.3\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       224.8s (!)
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: No, I'm unable to create the appBundle from Flutter, but I did create the app bundle by extracting the android module from Flutter.